# excluding input inside a div with a particular class from selector list

Tags: css, css-selectors

we have a class `has-error` which we applies to div which have inputs with error.

```
.has-error select, .has-error textarea, .has-error .mydp, .has-error input {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

But there is another div `mydp` which groups certain controls (input and buttons).so, using above `has-error` class we got 2 borders in that case.
I want to exclude `input` inside `.mydp` form above css selector.

I have tried

```
.has-error select, .has-error textarea, .has-error .mydp, .has-error input:not(.mydp input)
```

but don't know why it is excluding all inputs.

for now i am using

```
.has-error .mydp input {
  border: none !important;
}
```

to remove border form `input` inside `.mydp` and its working fine. But i want it to be excluded first selector itself.

```
.has-error select, .has-error textarea, .has-error .mydp, .has-error input {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
<div class="has-error">
    <div>
        <input />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="mydp"  >
            <input />
            <a href="#">btn</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `.mydp` inside the `div` to which you apply the class `has-error`?

Comment: Let us not guess, please provide your rendered html code, it is necessary to set the selectors.

Comment: This sounds like trying to find a parent selector **which does not exist**.

Comment: @skobaljic, i have updated question for with html